# "Could not connect to the server" when authenticateWithCredential

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I got such error

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
>   server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1744467e0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.243.48.203:9080/auth,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.243.48.203:9080/auth,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

when performed authenticateWithCredential into my iOS project

Can anybody help?Thanks!

Comment: "Could not connect to server" is the default error if it was unable to get any response from the URL you specified. This could mean your device wasn't connected to the network at the time, or your network isn't configured correctly. Either way, we need some more information about your setup here. Can you please explain what hardware you're using, and what set of network setup you have?

Comment: An SSL certificate is typically issued to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) such as "https://www.example.com". It seems wired you specify IP address on https. Maybe you should use domain name instead IP address or access by http (not http"s")?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, I think you should do this:

```
1.Install the macOS bundle Frome https://realm.io/cn/docs/get-started/installation/mac/
2.please Starting Realm Object Server
```

like this:[image]

```
3.you're using the localhost IP address`127.0.0.1`
```

[image]
    4.login in 
[image]
    5.You’re done! congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a non-SSL port, but asking the client to connect via SSL. This will probably not work.

Also, please note that SSL is disabled by default in the Realm Object Server, considering that we can not possibly provide a valid certificate in our installation packages. This is something that needs to be setup manually after installing the packages.

For reference, by default, if you enable SSL support, the port will be `9443`. If you didn't setup anything regarding SSL on the server, you will need to use port `9080`, which is non-SSL, so use `realm://` instead of `realms://`.